# Not able to connect to remote cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to access Cassandra(2.1.0) installed on my machine from other machine using my ip address. Here is how I am trying to do it in  other machine:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.3.51").build();
Session session = cluster.connect("adaequare");
```

But I am not able to access it. Here are few configurations from Cassandra installed on my machine:

```
listen_address: localhost
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
```

I tried changing localhost to my ip address. But it did not work either. Do I have to make any other changes in my cassandra.yaml to get this done?

Comment: Switching from localhost to your external IP address is important. After you did that, what error do you get when trying to connect?

Comment: Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, 'WSAECONNREFUSED')})

Comment: OK, this error shows that you are trying to connect to localhost (127.0.0.1) on the client side, where of course no Cassandra is running. This means your code snippet in your question is not what is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post the error. By saying "It didn't work" gives no clue at all.
Anyway, `rpc_address`in `cassandra.yaml` should point to the IP you configured. In case it is `192.168.3.51`, then it needs to go there.